# Can I modify an observable property inside the constructor?

Tags: javascript, mobx

I am struggling to find an answer regarding if the code below is valid in Mob-x 4:

```
@observer
class MyViewModel {
    @observable value;
    constructor() {
        this.value = 'Some value';
    }
}
```

Or, in order to make this code valid, would I need to wrap the line that modifies state in `runInAction`? - like this:

```
@observer
class MyViewModel {
    @observable value;
    constructor() {
        runInAction(() => { this.value = 'Some value' });
    }
}
```

I'm new to Mob-x but understand that from the documentation that observables are only allowed to be modified within an `action`. Since I'm trying to initialize the value in the constructor (which I don't believe can be marked as an `action`), I would imagine that the class properties have not yet become observable which is why I'm unsure if `runInAction` is needed - can someone please clarify?